# R namespace problems with 'logging' package

Tags: r, logging, namespaces, package, rstudio

I'm writing an R package that uses [the `logging` package from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logging/).  In my code, I initialize logging when my package is loaded:

```
#' @importFrom logging basicConfig
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  logging::basicConfig()
}

#' @importFrom logging setLevel
#' @export
setLogLevel <- function(level) {
  setLevel(level)
}
```

And in my `DESCRIPTION` file I declare the dependency:

```
Depends:
    R (>= 3.0.2),
    Rcpp (>= 0.11.2)
Imports:
    FNN,
    plyr,
    geosphere,
    logging
```

However, it looks like `R CMD check` (which I invoke via "Check Package" in RStudio) doesn't like something about the namespaces:

```
* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... WARNING
Loading required package: Rcpp
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for ‘ABC’, details:
  call: UseMethod("updateOptions")
  error: no applicable method for ‘updateOptions’ applied to an object of class "Logger"
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ABC’
Execution halted

It looks like this package (or one of its dependent packages) has an
unstated dependence on a standard package.  All dependencies must be
declared in DESCRIPTION.
See the information on DESCRIPTION files in the chapter ‘Creating R
packages’ of the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.

...

* checking for missing documentation entries ... ERROR
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ABC’
Call sequence:
2: stop(gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s", sQuote(package)), 
       call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
1: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The `updateOptions()` method it's complaining about is part of the `logging::basicConfig()` function I call in my initialization:

```
> logging::basicConfig
function (level = 20) 
{
    rootLogger <- getLogger()
    updateOptions(rootLogger, level = namedLevel(level))
    rootLogger$addHandler("basic.stdout", writeToConsole, level = namedLevel(level))
    invisible()
}
<environment: namespace:logging>

d> logging::updateOptions
function (container, ...) 
UseMethod("updateOptions")
<environment: namespace:logging>
```

Thanks for any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put logging in `depends` ?

Comment: Hi @agstudy, that does indeed seem to solve the problem.  It shouldn't, though, should it?  I don't really want to put the logging package in the user's namespace if I can avoid it.